# CollapsingToolBarLayout won't collapse with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Here's the complete layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D7D29ADC"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainToolbar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_anim_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                app:toolbarId="@id/searchToolbar">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/searchToolbar"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                    android:background="#A106A1"
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

                    <!-- dummy to catch focus -->
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="0px"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                        android:id="@+id/searchView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                        app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
                        app:searchHintIcon="@null" />

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What's wrong with this code that prevents toolbar from moving up and down with the RecyclerView?

Comment: you posted text filter but forgot to post "toolbar".. which is needed to find out the issue :)

Comment: @NehaK you mean the Java code for the toolbar? Which one? All I did programmatically was was add rounded corners for the `MaterialToolbar` and add the search function for the `SearchView`

Comment: no,         layout="@layout/toolbar"

Comment: @NehaK oh that's just the layout of the main toolbar. It just has a MetrialToolbar in it